# how can i apply dnd feature to a dynamically created div in html in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to apply dnd to dynamically created div using dojo. I have tried so many ways to apply dnd feature. Here is my code.

```
var inputdiv = document.createElement('div');
inputdiv.setAttribute("id", count);
inputdiv.style.background = "white";
inputdiv.style.height = "30px";
inputdiv.style.width = "60px";
dojo.addClass(inputdiv, "dojoDndItem");
calculation.appendChild(inputdiv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are manually adding DOM nodes with the `dojoDndItem` class to a dnd source's DOM node, you can call `sync` on the dnd source (the actual instance, *not* its DOM node) to make it update its data based on what is now in the DOM.

The `sync` method is listed in the [dojo/dnd documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dnd.html#public-methods-and-attributes).

Also, FWIW, you could do what you are doing in your code above more succinctly with `dojo.create` (you appear to be accessing Dojo APIs from the legacy globals so I will do the same in this example):

```
dojo.create('div', {
  className: 'dojoDndItem',
  id: count,
  // Note: it would be more ideal to apply styles via CSS rather than inline
  style: {
    background: 'white',
    height: '30px',
    width: '60px'
  }
}, calculation);
// Then call sync() on the dnd source once you've finished adding nodes
```

Comment: Incase if i want to make dynamically created div as Target how can i call sync().

Comment: If by Target you mean an instance of `dojo/dnd/Target`, that is simply an extension of `dojo/dnd/Source`, so the same principle would apply there.  Either way you will need a reference to the actual `dojo/dnd` instance.